# Can distribute setuptools be used to port packages implemented in python 2 to 3

Tags: python, c, build, python-3.x, package

Found some info on porting packages from python 2 to 3 using distribute setuptools in below link.

http://packages.python.org/distribute/python3.html

I have a C api which could be build using python 2.x, but i need to build it in python 3.x.
Can it be done using distribute.

Do anyone have idea on this?

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot be done using Distribute. Distribute just calls the `2to3` script in the build phase, but `2to3` can convert only between Python 2.x source files and Python 3.x source files. For the C API, you have to do it the hard way by manually tweaking your code to compile with both Python APIs.

A very incomplete list of C API changes between Python 2.x and Python 3.x is to be found [here](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#build-and-c-api-changes). The same document also outlines the major differences between Python 2.x and 3.x on the Python source code level.

Answer (score 0):

distriubte uses [Python's 2to3 tool](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) to automatically (try to) convert Python 2 code to Python 3 code.  However, that only works for code written in Python.  C code needs to be ported by hand.

The good news is that Python's C API has not changed much between Python 2.6 and 3.1.  The main difference is that Python 3 now uses Unicode for all strings and has a separate `bytes` type for handling raw binary data.

Comment: The changes are in fact quite big... The module initizlization code is completely different, for example.