# Can Distribute setuptool be used to convert Python 2 packages to Python 3?

Tags: python, events, python-3.x, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can distribute setuptools be used to port packages implemented in python 2 to 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774654/can-distribute-setuptools-be-used-to-port-packages-implemented-in-python-2-to-3)

Also, does [the tool](http://packages.python.org/distribute/) make it easy?

Comment: Same identicon avatar for the question asker too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that Distribute does is that it calls the `2to3` script (supplied with Python 3) that converts a Python 2.x source code to Python 3 using some automatic transformations. Basically, you write your code using Python 2.x and let Distribute convert it to Python 3 when your package is installed on Python 3.

There are several things that Distribute won't do for you, though:

- It won't check whether the conversion succeeded or not. You should have a fairly exhaustive set of unit tests to ensure that the behaviour of the converted package is correct as not all the transformations can be done automatically by `2to3`, and some other transformations it will do might not make sense. Read [this case study](http://diveintopython3.org/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html#running2to3) for more information about porting a real Python package to Python 3 and in particular [this section](http://diveintopython3.org/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html#manual) about things not handled by `2to3`.
- It won't convert modules written using the C API of Python (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774654/can-distribute-setuptools-be-used-to-port-packages-implemented-in-python-2-to-3)), you will have to convert these yourself.